# Combinatorics (Venn diagram problem)

Tags: combinatorics

On the planet Xprom: 12.000 creatures have horn, 15.000 creatures have tail and 20.000 creatures have NO FUR, 8.000 creatures have horn and tail, 6.000 creatures have tail and fur, 5.000 creatures have fur and horn, and 1.000 creatures have horn, fur and tail. What's the population of Xprom?

Comment: Why should I tell you? Please give context.

Comment: @Bero, remove combinatonics tag and put elementary set theory tag

Comment: @Vikram, nope. This is a combinatorics problem (inclusion/exclusion, to be more precise).

Comment: Yes it's inclusion/exclusion formula (IEF), but it's tricky because you have complement of one set

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Denote H - onlu with horn; T - only with tail, F - onlu with Fur.

HT - with horn and tail only, and so far.

Z - without horn, tail, fur (pure animals).

All the sets H,F,T, FH, FT,HT,FHT, Z are separated (drawn by different colors).

Then:

H + HT + FH + FHT = 12.000;
T + HT + FT + FHT = 15.000;
Z + H + HT + T = 20.000;

HT + FHT = 8.000;
FT + FHT = 6.000;
FH + FHT = 5.000;

FHT = 1.000.

Hence, (without zeroes):

HT = 8 - 1 = 7;
FT = 6 - 1 = 5;
FH = 5 - 1 = 4;

H = 12 - 1 - 7 - 4 = 0; (if someone has horn, then must have tail or fur);
T = 15 - 1 - 7 - 5 = 2;
Z = 20 - 7 - 0- 2 = 11;

---

Hmm, population of Xprom is undefined...
It is unknown how many persons live *with fur only*.

All I can tell that population is $\ge 30.000$.

Comment: something wrong with the problem, I am getting no fur creatures=10 and problem says it is 20

Comment: @Vikram, anyway, it is undefined amount of creatures with fur only. It can be arbitrary: as 0, as 10.000, as 100.000 .

Comment: Of course, there are $8$ different parts, but $7$ linear equations are given only. So, $1$ variable remains to be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using the inclusion/exclusion formula: given a population with (not necessarily disjoint) subsets $A_1, A_2,..,A_n$, the size of the union is given by (where $|A_i|$ is the size of the set $A_i$): $$| A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ...\cup A_n|=|A_1|\cup|A_2|\cup...\cup |A_n|- ( (A_1 \cap A_2)\cup (A_2 \cap A_3)\cup....) +..$$
(See , e.g.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion-exclusion_principle). Can you see how to apply this to your situation?